# Huge difference in performance when using .OGG/.MP3 vs .WAV, explanations?

Tags: android

I'm making a really small game for android, and trying to add sounds to the game
I'm using the MediaPlayer class to load the audio file (.ogg or .wav)

I want to use .ogg (or .mp3) to shrink the size of the apk, rather than using .wav files.

I understand why loading (i.e. creating the MediaPlayer from a .ogg would take longer than .wav) (compression)

BUT the problem is that when I put the audio on loop by `audio.setLooping(true)` each time the audio starts again, it lags the game significantly

Why ? does the audio gets decoded each time it's going to start ? even on a loop ?

Also, on the CPU usage, I see spikes marking the beginning of the audio in the loop. so I'm pretty sure that the loop is really causing the lag..

any explanations/solutions?

(P.s. I'm testing on a really low-end physical phone, but for the game it's fairly enough, the sudden spikes are what's causing the problem not the actual usage)

Comment: Perhaps on initial game load you could pull in audio files from a URL ... note that .wav files typically have NO compression ... I have written an OpenAL server which caches the raw audio for replay YMMV ... this repo gives android an audio cache https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache

Comment: `Huge difference in performance when using .OGG/.MP3 vs .WAV, explanations?` Yes: WAV files are **not compressed**, therefore they don't need to be decompressed. Which makes them **faster** to load.

Comment: BUT, in the start I load all the files and I construct all my objects, My question is about after loading, isn't a wav and a decompressed audio file should be the same in memory, and stay they since I don't release the MediaPlayer?? so why does looping the wav file is so smooth while looping the ogg or mp3 stutter at each iteration ?

Comment: Scott Stensland, It looks promising but I'm going only to use the game resource, the application is not a streaming service, so I think I have no way of using this sort of caching in my application,,, But I can't understand why native methods on playing audio and looping it (in the MediaPlayer) don't cache the audio file by default,,, normally they do, hence the existence of release() ...